# UITextField focus before navigation view push?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextField` set up in a `UITableViewCell`, for a control mimicking that in Apple's own Contacts app, when you go to edit a field. This is all *mostly* working fine, except for a little UI bug.

The `UITableView` is part of a `UIViewController` created and loaded from a XIB, but the text field is being created programmatically (and becoming first responder) in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so that it can be added to the cell.

This results in a slight keyboard lag, where the view controller is pushed onto the stack, with the keyboard coming soon after.

The Contacts app, however, pushes it all as one.

How can I correct this lag? I've tried moving the text field creation and first responder-ing to `viewDidLoad`, and this didn't help. I even tried creating a `layoutSubviews` and calling it from outside the view controller, before it was pushed to the stack.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem as though the text field actually *becomes* the first responder until it is part of the cell—well after the view has been pushed.

Comment: Could you explain more about when the view controller is pushed onto the stack? In my brief examination of the Contacts app I have not seen a keyboard shown simultaneously with a view controller push. When you push "Edit," all cells animate to edit mode, tapping a cell brings the keyboard up. Where does pushing a view controller come into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to let the `UITextField` become the first responder in `viewWillAppear`. 
I have created an example project here:

https://github.com/lukaswuerzburger/pushed-keyboard

Comment: This is the provable largest difference between the creation timestamp of a question and its accepted answer. On the whole site. Grat! :-)